# Compare two functions call graph on visual-studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, connection-leaks

In my situation, I would like to find out all the functions containing this function call

```
DBase.CreateCommand();
```

But not include the following call

```
DBase.CloseCommand(cmd);
```

In that function.

What I'm trying to do is to find out any not closed database connections.

A tool, plugin, regex etc. are all welcome.

Comment: Is there any reason why Ctrl+Shift+F for "CreateCommand()" (or even "DBase.CreateCommand()") is not a way here? It will search the whole solution for this method call, and it won't find overload with parameters for sure.

Comment: @Andei as I said on Davide Piras's answer, I want to compare these search results, they are too big to check them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of the method: `CreateCommand()` into a different name so you will get a bunch of errors at compile time and you will check those errors one by one?

or you can search by exact match: `"CreateCommand();"` or in Visual Studio, right click on the method then select Find All References...

Comment: I already know these solutions but what I'm exactly looking for is to compare these search results because the lists are too long

Answer (score 0):

You could try Resharper or something like that - whilst not providing a compare (that I know of) it will make them easier to modify as changes will ripple though and it has a lot of neat tools. Barring that Fortify scanning or other code analysis tools pick up un-released resources such as dbconns, and readers ect as well although I believe they may be quite pricey!